# Changed devise initializer, now authentication is broken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, initializer

I had tried to setup username based authentication in devise's initializer to begin with; but that turned out to require more work than I was willing to put into this app at this moment as it's just for mucking around with. So where I had initially had `config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]`, amongst other config settings, I changed them all back to `:email`.

Problem is though, now when I try and log in I now get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Devise::SessionsController#create
undefined method `email' for #<ActionDispatch::Request:0xrequestid>
```

I suspect it's related to my initial foray into username based authentication, but I can't tell where the actual problem/residual configuration is that I now need to address as I'm very new to Rails.

I'm more than happy to provide whatever logs/configuration/you name it. I just don't know what would be helpful at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it turns out that I shouldn't have specified the `config.authentication_keys` and `config.request_keys` when I changed them back to `[:email]` (the default). For whatever reason (which I don't know yet) this required me to specify the strong parameters, which were identical to what devise would have specified if I just left those lines commented.

So the simple solution is to not specify things if you are using the default value.

Answer (score 1):

do you have an :email field in your User model ? looks like Devise trying to get an email value when you login and failed on it.

Comment: I have a email field in the user table in the schema because it was generated when I created the migration.